# AQGridView Selection and Deselection

Tags: selection, aqgridview

I'm currently using AQGridView to display a photo gallery on my app, and I have a problem with the selection/deselection handling.

I can select a cell after inserting it in my galleryview

The way it goes is that, I can easily select both cells, but if I want to deselect one, it has to be one I haven't just clicked on. My problem is I want to be able to select/unselect like the tableview editing mode behavior.

so if I click on the right one like this

[image]

I won't be able to deselect it, unless I click on an other cell like this

[image]

Then I can unselect the previous cell like this

[image]

And return to no cell selected. But in no way I can deselect a cell if it is the only one I've added in my gallery.

The deselect/select works perfectly well, and that is the thing I don't understand.

here is my code for AQGridView didSelectItemAtIndex

```
- (void) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridview didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSLog(@"SELECT");
GalleryGridViewCell * cell = (GalleryGridViewCell *)[self.gridView cellForItemAtIndex:index];
[cell selectImg:TRUE];
[imgList addObject:cell.image];
//sentImg = plainCell.image;
}
```

here is my code for AQGridView didDeselectItemAtIndex

```
 -(void)gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didDeselectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
NSLog(@"img deselected %@ at index %d", plainCell.image, index);
GalleryGridViewCell * cell = (GalleryGridViewCell *)[self.gridView cellForItemAtIndex:index];
[cell selectImg:FALSE];
if (imgList != nil)
    [imgList removeObject:cell.image];
}
```

and here is a method I added for my GalleryGridViewCell selectImg:(BOOL) selection

```
-(void) selectImg:(BOOL) selection
{
if (selection == TRUE)
{
    [_checkBoxBttn setSelected:TRUE];
    [self setSelected:TRUE];
}
if (selection == FALSE)

{
    [_checkBoxBttn setSelected:FALSE];
    [self setSelected:FALSE];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your gridView:didSelectItemAtIndex method, try deselecting the item using
[gridView deselectItemAtIndex:index animated:animated];

That should do the job.